# Why does a UIRoundedRectButton not respond yes to isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I have a `UIButton` in a view that is created with

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(500, 100, 100, 44);
[self.view addsubview:btn];
```

When I loop through the view hierarchy like this:

```
for (id view in self.view.subviews) 
{        
    NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromClass([view class]));
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) 
    {
        //dsnt get here
        UIButton *btn = view;
    }
}
```

control never enters the if block.

`NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([view class]));` prints "UIRoundedRectButton". How do I check if the class is `UIButton`?

`UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] init];` gives the desired result, but I cannot set the button type later.

Comment: Have you added the button to your view? [self.view addSubView:btn]; ?

Comment: This seems like a very odd thing to want to do. What are you trying to do with this code?

Comment: try `[view isMemberOfClass:[UIButton class]];` I find if one doesn't work the other works perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing this sample one for you..it works perfectly...

```
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 160, 50);
[myButton setTitle:@"click me" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:myButton];

for (id view in self.view.subviews)
{

    NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromClass([view class]));

    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])

    {
        //dsnt get here
        UIButton *btn = view;
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
for (UIButton *btnNew in self.view.subviews) 
{        
    NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromClass([btnNew class]));
    if ([btnNew isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) 
    {
     //dsnt get here
     UIButton *btn = btnNew;
     }
}
```